# How to fetch items in a map function for each ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to fetch some data with the Wordpress API and i need to do this based on the restbase and ID.

I have an array that looks like this:

```
const array = [
    {
        taxonomy: 'category',
        rest_base: 'categories',
        id: [ 1, 2 ]
    },
    {
        taxonomy: 'post_tag',
        rest_base: 'tags',
        id: [ 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
    }
];
```

This is the map function:

```
array.map( ({ rest_base, id }) => {
    console.log( rest_base ); // categories or tags
    console.log( id ); // array of id's

    // Do a call here for each id
});
```

I need to somehow get all the individual ID's so i can make calls like:

```
example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/<rest_base>/<id>
```

Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: No feedback on any of the answers given after 9 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the outer array with `Array.flatMap()` and the `id` array with `Array.map()` make the calls with `fetch` or similar APIs, and you'll get an array of promises:

```js
const array = [{"taxonomy":"category","rest_base":"categories","id":[1,2]},{"taxonomy":"post_tag","rest_base":"tags","id":[4,5,6,7]}];

const result = array.flatMap( ({ rest_base, id }) => 
  id.map(v => `example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/${rest_base}/${v}`) // wrap the string with a fetch or similar function
);

console.log(result);
```

If you can't use `Array.flatMap()` use nested `Array.map()` call, and flatten by spreading into `Array.concat()`:

```js
const array = [{"taxonomy":"category","rest_base":"categories","id":[1,2]},{"taxonomy":"post_tag","rest_base":"tags","id":[4,5,6,7]}];

const result = [].concat(...array.map( ({ rest_base, id }) => 
  id.map(v => `example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/${rest_base}/${v}`) // wrap the string with a fetch or similar function
));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works exactly how i wanted it to work, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use any http request library. The simplest way to use the browser's fetch API with async / await:

```
const resultArray = array.map( async({ rest_base, id }) => {
    console.log( rest_base ); // categories or tags
    console.log( id ); // array of id's

    return id.map(id => await fetch(`example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/${rest_base}/${id}`));

});
```

The await function will return the result of the call. This way you can fetch data synchronously. It it is ok for you to get data asynchrony you can create an array of promises and use Promise all:

```
const promiseArray = array.map( async({ rest_base, id }) => {
    console.log( rest_base ); // categories or tags
    console.log( id ); // array of id's

    return id.map(id => return fetch(`example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/${rest_base}/${id}`));
});

const result = Promise.all(promiseArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use `Array.prototype.reduce` to create an object where the keys are your `rest_base` values, and the values are the corresponding `id` values. On that, you can simply iterate like below:

```js
const arr = [{
    taxonomy: 'category',
    rest_base: 'categories',
    id: [1, 2]
  },
  {
    taxonomy: 'post_tag',
    rest_base: 'tags',
    id: [4, 5, 6, 7]
  }
];

const map = arr.reduce((acc, val) => {return {...acc, [val.rest_base]: val.id}}, {});
/*
{
  "categories": [
    1,
    2
  ],
  "tags": [
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7
  ]
}
*/
for (const rest_base in map) {
  for (const id of map[rest_base]) {
    console.log(`example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/${rest_base}/${id}`) 
  }
}
/*
example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/1
example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/2
example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags/4
example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags/5
example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags/6
example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags/7
*/
```